# How to get element value using minidom in python and store them into a list?

Tags: python, xml

Here is my code snippet:-

```
from xml.dom import minidom
from xml.dom.minidom import parse
xmldoc = minidom.parse('C:\\Users\\folder\\Documents\\Python Training\\XMLFiles\\sample.xml')

dimension = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("tns:RefDimensionSet")[0]
fields = dimension.getElementsByTagName("tns:Field")

for field in fields:
    print field
```

This produces this output which seems to be alright:-

```
<DOM Element: tns:Field at 0x2a46988>
<DOM Element: tns:Field at 0x2a46b08>
<DOM Element: tns:Field at 0x2a46c88>
<DOM Element: tns:Field at 0x2a46e08>
<DOM Element: tns:Field at 0x2a46f88>
<DOM Element: tns:Field at 0x2a47148>
<DOM Element: tns:Field at 0x2a472c8>
<DOM Element: tns:Field at 0x2a47448>
<DOM Element: tns:Field at 0x2a475c8>
<DOM Element: tns:Field at 0x2a47748>
```

It displays the address of the elements, I want to display the values themselves instead and then store those values in a list as string elements.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function *getElementsByTagName* returns an object of type DOM Element, this is why you get this result. I.e. if you want to access to the value of an attribute call *id* of that element you can try this:

```
field.attributes['id'].value
```

Comment: Thanks alot. That sorted it out